# What is the timebase of the timestamp of CameraDevice

Tags: android, timestamp, android-camera2

I have run into problem with timestamps and I would appreciate if someone could help me. I am trying to synchronize the SensorEvent to the Images that I receive from the ImageReader.

I am aware that the timestamp of the SensorEvent is the nanoseconds since the operating system started (uptime).
On the other hand the getTimestamp of the Image (that comes from the ImageReader) is measured in nanoseconds but the timebase depends on the source providing the images (Camera, CameraDevice, etc). In my case I am using the CameraDevice (camera2) but I haven't found what is the timebase of the CameraDevice.

I would appreciate any help.
Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is documented in the [SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE) field, though of the two options, the first will likely not help you.

- UNKNOWN: "Timestamps from android.sensor.timestamp are in nanoseconds and monotonic, but can not be compared to timestamps from other subsystems (e.g. accelerometer, gyro etc.), or other instances of the same or different camera devices in the same system. Timestamps between streams and results for a single camera instance are comparable, and the timestamps for all buffers and the result metadata generated by a single capture are identical."
- REALTIME: "Timestamps from android.sensor.timestamp are in the same timebase as elapsedRealtimeNanos(), and they can be compared to other timestamps using that base."

Unfortunately, most devices today report UNKNOWN, since they do not have precise synchronization to the timebase used by [elapsedRealtimeNanos()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtimeNanos()) (which at the Linux kernel level, is generally the [CLOCK_BOOTTIME](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) time source).

However, in practice, most devices' camera timestamps are just from the CLOCK_MONOTONIC source, which is generally the same timebase as [nanoTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()).

But the timestamping is often not very accurate (meanining, off by several milliseconds), which is why these devices report UNKNOWN, since the timestamp accuracy is not high enough to reliably correlate to other sensors' timestamps.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much Eddy.

Comment: So if I understand correctly this is a read only flag and not something which can be set to get a time stamp whose base is fixed correctly! I have noticed that the time stamp reported by the IMU and that by the camera differ widely! e.g. by a much as 1 second! Has there been any improvement? If I still want a reasonable enough synchronization what can be done?

Comment: If the camera device reports UNKNOWN, and the sensors are using REALTIME (which I believe is the case), then the difference can be very large since one doesn't increment while the device is asleep.   While the camera is running, the difference is unlikely to grow (since the device will not go to sleep), so you can in principle measure both times at start and use that difference to correct the timestamps to the same timebase.